# Pass Angular html template to backbone template

Tags: angularjs, templates, backbone.js, typescript, marionette

I'm trying to slowly convert a Backbone App to Angular.  It's actually using Marionette to be precise.  In each of my current Marionette views, they are a Marionette.ItemView.  For the template to show, I do this:

```
    get template() {
        return _.template(nameOfMyTemplate, { myModel: this.model });
    }
```

nameOfMyTemplate would be my AwesomeTemplate.template.html file that is in my solution.

I was wondering how I could go about just passing my template.html without calling _.template in a backbone or marionette app?  So somewhere in my backbone view or marionette.itemview, I could do

```
template: NewAwesomeAngularTemplate.template.html // where NewAwesomeAngularTemplate.template.html is a file in my solution
```

Has anyone come across this yet?  I wasn't able to find much info on how people were converting their apps to Angular from Backbone or Marionette.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marionette expects all templates to be immediately available, not having to be fetched async.  The view.template function can be easily overwritten but it needs to immediately return a string (or return a function that will immediately return a string).

There was an old fork called Marionette.Async which enabled fetching of templates on-demand but it was abandonded long ago after the maintainers determined it to be A Really Bad Idea.

Your best bet is to build a mechanism that either loads all the templates into memory up front (like embedding them in a single JS file or the main HTML page) or a custom mechanism that ensures templates are fetched as-needed *before* the view gets used.  The former will be much easier but viability depends on how many templates you have and how big they are.

Answer (score 0):

Not too familiar with Backbone or Marionette, but went over and looked at the website.

I am not sure if this is what you are asking, so excuse me if I am way off base. In Angular you can use the ngRouter or the more powerful uiRouter to bind your urls to controllers and views.

```
state('index', {
  url: "/",
  controller: 'SomeController',
  templateUrl: "template/NewAwesomeAngularTemplate.html"
})
```

Not sure if this is what you were looking for. If so, check out the documentation at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grunt ts html2ts support : https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts#html-2-typescript-support

It turns an html file into a typescript string variable which you can return from the template function.

Comment: this seems not relevant